# Mirages and other metaphors

Tags: metaphors

The word *mirage*, when used metaphorically, can mean a false hope of a desperate person.

But it would also seem to make sense to use that metaphor to mean an initial appearance that vanishes on closer inspection.

What would be the pros and cons of the latter usage; in particular, will some misunderstand it to mean the former usage, and is there a better short expression (preferably just one word) for the latter sense?

Comment: Shouldn't context collapse the meaning to the one intended? Actually, what _is_ the context? Give the full sentence.

Comment: @Mitch : Just before posting this, I wrote "So although it may at first appear that $\theta_1$ is not a 'diagonal' angle measure
in the usual sense of _diagonal_, that appearance is a mirage." I did not intend this to mean a false hope, but only an initial appearance seen to be incorrect on further inspection.

Comment: @Mitch : Actually I should have written this: "So although it may at first appear that $\theta_1$ is not the measure of an angle between two adjacent diagonals in the usual sense of _diagonal_, that appearance is a mirage."

Comment: 1) 'mirage' is understood in the way you intend, 'incorrect initial appearance'. 2) The meaning you intend happens to imply the other meaning, 'false hope'. 3) Since this is mathematical-technical writing, I would tend away from metaphorical language. It is compelling enough to say that the appearance is misleading.

Comment: I'd go with *illusion*

Comment: The reason "mirage" has become associated with false hopes is because a well known mirage is an oasis in a desert.

Comment: I'm tempted to say "that appearance is illusory." But an illusion persists even after you know it's an illusion, whereas this is about an appearance that does not persist after its erroneous nature is understood.